# azure pipeline yaml errors when saving a commit to bitbucket

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket, azure-pipelines-yaml

Getting this error THE URI STRING IS TOO LONG while saving a change from my azure pipeline yaml.

It just happened out of the blue. Anyone have any thoughts?

[image]

tried modifying directly in bitbucket and have no problems...

Comment: figured out the issue.
when modifying azure-pipelines.yml in azure devops, there is a somehow a limit to the lines you can commit to bitbucket (not sure if other hubs have the same problem)

i currently had 1627 lines. I tried reducing them down to 1612 and was able to save from azure devops.